# Joining data conditioning both collections

Tags: mongodb

Having two collections, first a collection called firstcollection with elements such as

`{ uid:12345, pid:777, comment="first" }`

and other, called secondcollection with elements such as

`{ uid:12345, extra:17 }`

How would I be able to obtain an output that joins both collections by uid, while at the same time, it satisfies a condition in both collections (for example, that the comment field exists on firstcollection, and that the extra field is higher than 15 on secondcollection.

For now this is what I've tried:

```
var x = db.firstcollection.find({comment:{$exists:true}})
db.secondcollection.aggregate({
  $lookup:
  {
    from: "x",
    localField: "uid",
    foreignField: "uid",
    as: "aggregation"
  }
})
```

But I'm completely unsure if I'm going the right way or not, and also have no idea on how to query secondcollection so it satisfies the condition I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

@wazowski.... it would help you refer it once db.post.aggregate([ { "$match": { "rating":"important" } }, { "$sort": { "date": -1 } }, {"$limit": 20 }, { "$lookup": { "localField":"user_id", "from": "user", "foreignField": "_id","as": "userinfo" } }, { "$unwind": "$userinfo" }, {"$project": { "text": 1, "date": 1,"userinfo.name": 1, "userinfo.country": 1 } }]);

And if you're begginer then it is clear explanation for you...

db.users.aggregate([ // Join with user_info table
 { $lookup:{ from: "userinfo", // other table name localField: "userId", // name of users table field foreignField: "userId", // name of userinfo table field as: "user_info" // alias for userinfo table } }, { $unwind:"$user_info" }, // $unwind used for getting data in object or for one record only // Join with user_role table { $lookup:{ from: "userrole", localField: "userId", foreignField: "userId", as: "user_role" } }, { $unwind:"$user_role" }, // define some conditions here { $match:{ $and:[{"userName" : "admin"}] } }, // define which fields are you want to fetch { $project:{ _id : 1, email : 1, userName : 1, userPhone : "$user_info.phone", role : "$user_role.role", } } ]);

This will give result like this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"), "email" : "admin@gmail.com", "userName" : "admin", "userPhone" : "0000000000", "role" : "admin" }

Comment: It still fails while doing the $unwind, I get this:

 "errmsg" : "expected either a string or an object as specification for $unwind stage, got undefined",

Comment: @Wazowski....because your not giving anything to $unwind ..so ,please make sure once again!!